# Cygwin - how to edit a read only file?

Tags: cygwin, text-editing, read-only

I'm trying to edit /etc/hosts using Vi in Cygwin but it's read only.  Is there a command similar to sudo?  How do I edit a read-only file?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing a forced overwrite.  Instead of `:wq` to write and quit, try: `:wq!` to force write and quit.

Comment: Didn't work....

Comment: Try using the Windows `runas` command then?  `runas /user:Administrator vi /etc/hosts`

Comment: Running cygwin as administrator allowed me to edit the file.  Thanks for your help

Comment: @Nope You should accept the newer answer posted by Philipp if you ever sign on again!

Answer (score 7):

Opening your cygwin shell as Administrator will grant your user root access. Then the files will no longer be readonly.